# How to filter data from JSON in python

Tags: python

I am working in pyton and using a JSON file and pulling info from it and sending to a csv file, the code I am using is as follows:

```
import csv
import json

csv_kwargs = {
    'dialect': 'excel',
    'doublequote': True,
    'quoting': csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
}

inpfile = open('checkin.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') 
outfile = open('checkin.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

writer = csv.writer(outfile, **csv_kwargs, lineterminator="\n")

for line in inpfile:
    d = json.loads(line)
    writer.writerow([d['business_id'],d['date']])

inpfile.close()
outfile.close()
```

checkin.json has a date element that has both date of'MM:DD:YYYY' and time of 'HH:MM:SS'.  My question is how do you code this to keep the date, but not the time being that they are in the same element.

Comment: BTW, if you're trying to do a hash-bang, it's `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Comment: Why are you loading the json file line by line? Is it not a json file?

Comment: (It would be easier if you showed a few samples from the files.)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @MateenUlhaq this file is just what I was given to edit.  I do not know alot about Python to tell you why it was done in this way.  I know it inputs a JSON file and does athe for line in inpfile and sends that info to a .csv file.  All i need is a few lines in this area, just not sure what the code should be